# Compile vim from source on Ubuntu 16.04 with python failure

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, python, compiling, vim

I am trying to compile vim from source with python or python3, but they are never present after installation. I am following [the instructions from youcompleteme wiki](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source) and have installed VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0, more specifically version 8.0.579.

I copy pasted the `./configure` and found out that I don't have my python config file where the guide said I should. So I used `which python` to see where python is. And sure enough I found the file in `/usr/bin/python3.5-config` and changed the `./configure` script. I found vim80 in `/usr/local/share/vim/vim80` so there is where I sat my `VIMRUNTIMEDIR`. Then I did `sudo make install`. No errors. And no Python...

How do I add python to vim80? Am I selecting the wrong python config file? I have installed all the dependencies mentioned at the top of the GitHub page and uninstalled any previous vim installations, as well as searched for the folders where they were previously so the previous installation is completely removed to avoid messing with the new vim80.

Comment: If you only wanted to get vim8 on 16.04, checkout this ppa instead https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vim

Comment: I ran vim.nox and executed "echo has('python3')" and it returned a "1"! But when I execute "vim" I get version 8.0.579 which doesn't have python. and in /usr/bin/vim I got vim 8.0.582 which doesn't have python either. I executed "echo $VIMRUNTIME in the 3 vim windows and one, without python, points to "/usr/local/share/vim" where no vim folder is and the other two to "/usr/share/vim/vim80/". So I got 2 different versions of vim pointing to the same runtime dir. Any fix?

Comment: Have you removed all instance before? Can you share your parameters for `./configure`?

Comment: Yes I have but "vim 8.0.579" wont go away. I compiled from source and then I did "sudo make uninstall" and deleted all the folders with the name vim but when I execute vim it's still there, even though I removed it. My config was './configure --with-features=huge --enable-multibyte  --enable-pythoninterp=yes  --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/  --enable-python3interp=yes --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.5/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/  --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope --prefix=/usr'

Comment: I mean the parameters for `.configure` which you'd do with vim build. Do You know that you can't use both python2 and 3 in vim? Also the configs are in `/usr/lib/python3.5` or 2.7 here on 16.04. Have you removed system python?

Comment: I know you can't use python2 and 3, I've tried with only python2 and only python3 but that doesn't seem to work either. I got my config at /usr/lib/python3.5 too. I tried setting "--with-python3-config-dir=" to both /usr/lib/python3.5 and /usr/lib/python3.5/config-x86_64-l‌​inux-gnu/, the latter is where my config.c is located. Same goes for python2.

Comment: Have you set config to `/usr/lib/python3.5/config`?

Comment: Tried that too, now I need help removing vim 8.0.579, but I deleted the source folder from where I installed it in and I removed ALL folders with the name "vim" in any /usr/  and all /bin/, but vim still runs on that version. I installed vim via the ppa that you recommended and it apparently works with python.  So now when I execute "vim" in console I get vim 8.0.579 which is uninstalled and completely deleted and when I go to /usr/bin/ and execute "./vim" I get version 8.0.558 which works with python but isn't the default vim. How do I uninstall the old "uninstalled" vim?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by installing everything from https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vim and setting an alias of "vim-nox" equal to vim in .bashrc and thus overwriting the old vim command from the vim that doesn't work making the only vim command that work connected to the vim that actually works.